# Eigenvalues of $A$ if $A^2=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A:V\to V$ be an endomorphism of a vector space $V$ such that $A^2=id$.

Then the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$ and of course $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Are those in fact eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Why do you say "of course"?  Is it necessarily true that $1$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: That's what I am asking

Comment: Look at $2\times2$ matrices and see.

Comment: Ok, so $\pm 1$ aren't necessarily eigenvalues

Comment: No polynomial equation ever forces a particular value to be an eigenvalue, because $V$ can have dimension $0$ and there will be no eigenvalues at all. Also as soon as there are at least two possible eigenvalues, you can avoid one or the other of them (in positive dimension) using a scalar matrix.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen no polynomial equation except for $A = \lambda I$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: No, you are wrong. In dimension$~0$, even $\lambda I$ has no eigenvalues. Remember eigenvectors have to be nonzero. (And of course $\lambda I$ is just a silly way to denote the unique endomorphism.)

Comment: @Marc fair point